# R: List of base Math functions

Tags: r, list, function, math

I want to get a list of available math functions without looking in index. I tried ls(), methods(), lsf() commands.  I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

This will get you started, but I don't know how to identify "math functions" in base.  You could run this, copy to Excel and sort as you wish to have a set:

```
lsf.str("package:base")
```

Answer (score 2):

See `?Math` for mathematics functions:

> Group "Math":
>
> abs, sign, sqrt, floor, ceiling, trunc, round, signif
>
> exp, log, expm1, log1p, cos, sin, tan, cospi, sinpi, tanpi, acos,
>   asin, atan
>
> cosh, sinh, tanh, acosh, asinh, atanh
>
> lgamma, gamma, digamma, trigamma
>
> cumsum, cumprod, cummax, cummin
>
> Members of this group dispatch on x. Most members accept only one
>   argument, but members log, round and signif accept one or two
>   arguments, and trunc accepts one or more.

Comment: The other groups are also relevant here.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at

Advanced R, Vocabulary (by Hadley Wickham)?

http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Vocabulary.html

That gives you the basic math functions in 'The basics' section plus much more. All conveniently in one place. And the full book is an awesome read too (IMHO the best out there for understanding how to really work with R).